SQL cummulative count over time but not starting at 0
I would like to do a cumulative count over time on some records.  However I want the count to start at a specific amount (leftovers from previous month not included in data) for example start at 50.
With the following data:



Rep
Sale Date




Bill
6/1/24


Jim
6/1/24


Bob
6/3/24



The result of the count should be something similar to:



Sale Date
Count




6/1/24
52


6/2/24
52


6/3/24
53



I tried just adding 50 to the column but that gave 50 + whatever the count was from that individual date as opposed to 50 + cumulative sum up until that date (using the above data it gave a result of: 52, 50, 51).

Please include your current query and an [mre] to make this easier to debug for others. This also increases your chances of getting a useful answer. Otherwise you're asking us to put in extra time to create a working example just to be able to test a possible solution. Help us help you!

Union 50 dummy records onto the front of your data :)

WITH 
dates_cte AS (
    SELECT (
        DATE '1/1/24' + (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,2))
    )::DATE AS date
),
sum_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        d.date as sale_date, 
        COUNT(o.sale_date) AS date_count
    FROM original_table o
    RIGHT JOIN dates_cte d ON date_trunc('month', o.sale_date) = date_trunc('month', d.date)
    GROUP BY d.date
)

SELECT 
    sale_date, 
    50 + SUM(date_count) OVER(
        ORDER BY sale_date
        ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    ) AS cumsum 
FROM sum_cte

dates_cte generates series of months. It's needed in case of some months are missing in the original table. Here you can vary the range of months.
sum_cte simply counts sales for every month. I didn't know how exactly you wanted to group by months, so I just trunc all dates to start of the month.
And finally we calculate cumulative sum using counts from sum_cte. Looks like AWS needs explicit frame clause in window function, so I added "ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING".

Unfortunately this was close but didn't work: gives back "ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause"
Swapping out order by for partition by and removing the order by at the end gets it to work but i get the same number of rows instead of an aggregate as expected.  I.e. a date with two rows will show 2 rows with the correct count instead of a single row with the correct count.

Yes, sorry for mistake, I edited the answer.
